# SelectSingleNode and InnerText in XML file

Tags: c#, xml, innertext, selectsinglenode

I have the following code:

```
if (doc.DocumentElement.Name == "SOAP-ENV:Envelope")
   {
    string xmlEnv = doc.DocumentElement.InnerXml;
    doc.LoadXml(xmlEnv);
    if (doc.DocumentElement.Name == "SOAP-ENV:Body")
    {
     string xmlBody = doc.DocumentElement.InnerXml;
                    doc.LoadXml(xmlBody);
                    if (doc.DocumentElement.Name == "NS1:RecebeMensagemResponse")
                    {
                        foreach (XmlNode ns1 in doc)
                        {
                            **sldfinl = doc.SelectSingleNode("//SldFinl").InnerText;**
                            dthrbc = doc.SelectSingleNode("//DtHrBC").InnerText;
                            dtmovto = doc.SelectSingleNode("//DtMovto").InnerText;
```

And I have the following information in my XML. The first line in bold in the code above ( **sldfinl = doc.SelectSingleNode("//SldFinl").InnerText;**) is returning null but what I'm looking for is in XML below in bold(<**SldFinl**>2000437760.49</**SldFinl**>)

-<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

-<SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:NS1="urn:JDSPBCAB_Intf-IJDSPBCAB" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">

-NS1:RecebeMensagemResponse

ALS99

JDCCAB00000000025309

38166

60814191

BMB202103105

STR0014R1

20210310093440

R

STR0014R1<NumCtrlIF_LDL>BMB202103105</NumCtrlIF_LDL><ISPBIF_LDL>60814191</ISPBIF_LDL>2021-03-10T07:30:002000437760.49<Grupo_STR0014R1_Lanc>STR0007R1<NumCtrlIF_LDLOr>01000841321009075999</NumCtrlIF_LDLOr>60701190STR202103100330260052021-03-10T09:30:41<TpDeb_Cred>D</TpDeb_Cred>9.50</Grupo_STR0014R1_Lanc>2000437750.992021-03-10T09:34:222021-03-10

<Numero_Mensagem xsi:type="xsd:string">28800</Numero_Mensagem>

</NS1:RecebeMensagemResponse>

</SOAP-ENV:Body>

</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
and the program is returning -> System.Xml.XmlNode.SelectSingleNode(...) returned null.

Am I missing something?

Thank you in advance

Arcturus

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and stepping through your code/setting watches? That should go a long way in narrowing down your problem.

Comment: Yes, I am doing that. I collected the XML content from the debug in my breakpoint but stillnot undertand what went wrong.

Comment: The program show the following error message:
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @ArcturusGonzalez, please edit your post and provide your Input XML and format it properly.

Comment: Looks like your missing the namespace as the 2nd parameter to SelectSingleNode( strXPath, nsmgr).  Forgetting about namespaces is the single most common XPath issue. 
Create a name table, and a namespace manager, update your XPath to use the namespace, and add the namespace manager to your SelectSingleNode / SelectNodes calls.